# Stock Items Quantity

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js, vuex

I am using Vue.js for this.

I have a Stock Items Quantity. I have added a function to that to decrease that number value after submit. The function works, it does decrement the value, but after the page is refreshed or reloaded the quantity returns to its original state!

How can I make the quantity persistent?

The Product.js Model

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const HomeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    title:String,
    category:String,
    image:String,
    description:String,
    detail:String,
    stock:Number,
    price:Number,
    star:Number,
    cast:String,
    director:String,
    isDeleted:{type: Boolean, default: false},
    updated_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Products', HomeSchema);
```

And this is the Route of Product.js

```
var Products = require('../models/Products');
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router = express.Router();

var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');


var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, '../static/images/')
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    let ext = file.originalname.substring(file.originalname.indexOf(".") + 1);
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + "." + ext)
  }
});
var upload = multer({
  storage: storage
});

/* GET ALL products */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Products.find(function (err, products) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(products);
    });
  });

/* GET SINGLE PRODUCT BY ID */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Products.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(post);
    });
  });

  /* SAVE PRODUCT 
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Products.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
      if (err) retu rn next(err);
      res.json(post);
    });
  });*/

  router.post('/', upload.single('image'),
    function (req, res) {
      let products = req.body;
      products.name = req.body.name
      products.title = req.body.title
      products.category = req.body.category
      products.image = req.body.image != 'undefined' ? req.file.filename : null
      products.price = req.body.price
      products.description = req.body.description
      products.detail = req.body.detail
      products.stock = req.body.stock
      products.star = req.body.star
      products.director = req.body.director
      products.cast = req.body.cast
      Products.create(products, function (err, post) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(post);
      });

  });
```

This is the HTML

```html
<input 
  type="submit" @click="decrement(product)" 
  class="btn btn-warning btn-user btn-block" value="Buy"
/>
<p class="text-danger text-center pt-2">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    Only {{product.stock}} items left in stock!
</p>
```

**This is the function I am using (THE COMPLETE SCRIPT)**

```
<script>
/* eslint-disable */
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'CreateBuyform',
  data () {
    return {
      rezervimet: {},
      prodId:this.$route.params.Pid,
      productfield:{},
    }
  },
    created() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/products`)

    .then(response => {
      this.productfield = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
     },
     computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
// map `this.user` to `this.$store.getters.user`
      user: "user"
    })
  },
  methods: {
     onSubmit(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();



          var bodyFormData = new FormData();

          bodyFormData.set("prodid", document.getElementById("prodid").value);
          bodyFormData.set("userid", document.getElementById("userid").value);
          bodyFormData.set("address", document.getElementById("address").value);
          bodyFormData.set("phoneNumber", document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value);
          bodyFormData.set("city", document.getElementById("city").value);

          axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/rezervimet`, bodyFormData)
      .then(response => {
        //console.log(response);
        this.$router.push({
          name: '',
          //params: { id: response.data._id }
        })
        })
    },
    decrement(product){
      product.stock--;
      if(product.stock == 0){
        alert("No items in stock");
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: How are you getting the original quantity? Are you pulling that value from Mongo? It sounds like you aren't changing the quantity in Mongo after decreasing the quantity in Vue.

Comment: Where do you get `product` from? Surely this should come from your backend with the latest stock quantity? The persistence should be implemented on your backend.

Comment: Yes @MattOestreich , the " product " is coming from mongoDB , that is what I'm trying to do but I don't know how!!

Comment: @Beyers I'm getting it from the database in MongoDB

Comment: You have to send a request to your backend when someone decreases the quantity, your backend should then update Mongo with the new quantity. Just as you are sending a request to your backend, which gets the original quantity, you need to have a route which you can send a request to which tells your backend you need to update the quantity in Mongo. It would be extremely helpful if you could provide all of the code you are using.. like, how you get the original quantity and your backend route that handles it.

Comment: @MattOestreich Just edited hope this helps a bit!!

Comment: What does `Product.create` do? Don't see where you're decreasing stock/quantity from your db.